# How to make a reusable param function in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I have several pages in my Svelte app that has the same function, so I wanted to make a component containing that function in hope that they are reusable. Then I saw several SO answers regarding this, but none of them seems to work, maybe I miss something but I don't know what did I miss.

So first I created a component (PageGetImageName.svelte) that contains an export function:

```
<script>
    export function getImageName(imagePath) {
        if (imagePath !== null) {
            let lastIndex = imagePath.lastIndexOf('/');
            return imagePath.substring(lastIndex + 1);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then I import that component, created a variable, bind that variable to the component, and finally calling the function in my page (Index.svelte):

```
<script>
    import PageGetImageName from '../../Components/PageGetImageName.svelte';

    let pageGetImageNameComponent;
</script>

<PageGetImageName bind:this={pageGetImageNameComponent} />

<td class="align-middle white-space-nowrap py-0">
    <div class="border rounded-2">
        <img src="/storage/admin-console/products-and-solutions/{row.image}" alt="{pageGetImageNameComponent.getImageName(row.image)}" width="53">
    </div>
</td>
```

But that doesn't work, I got 2 console errors:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e[4] is undefined

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n is undefined
```

And since I'm using run build, the code that's running in the browser is the minified function. This makes it hard for me to debug (can't use run dev for reasons). But it's definitely caused by this reusable function since the error doesn't exist before. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to to be any point in the function being in a component, it should just be exported from a regular JS or TS file.

If you really want to export a function from a Svelte file, export it from [`<script context="module">`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-context-module) if it does not require a component instance.

It then can be directly imported as a named import (`import { functionName } from './some-file.svelte'`) from the Svelte file and does not require a component to be added in the markup to use.

---

The error happens because you access a bound variable before it is initialized. In general when using `bind:this`, you can wrap the section of the HTML that accesses the variable in an `{#if componentVariable}` to make sure the code is not executed too early.

Comment: Yes, I guess there is no point if it's just a JavaScript function and not including HTML. I did tried creating a JS file before but failed during npm run build. But now I see what I missed, I should've put them inside curly bracket. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using it wrong. This is how you need to do it:

```
<script>
    import PageGetImageName, { getImageName } from '../../Components/PageGetImageName.svelte';
</script>

<PageGetImageName />

<td class="align-middle white-space-nowrap py-0">
    <div class="border rounded-2">
        <img src="/storage/admin-console/products-and-solutions/{row.image}" alt="{getImageName(row.image)}" width="53">
    </div>
</td>
```

See the official tutorial for more details: https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/module-exports